# httpHead and httpClient giving 503

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm having an issue where I'm firing a http request to get the headers like this. My aim is to check that when I fire the request a response is given back to me.

```
    try {
        HttpHead headReq = new HttpHead(imageUrl);
        response = (CloseableHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(headReq);
        StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
        if (sl.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            //do something
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            response.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I keep getting a HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable even though I know the URL exists when I hit it in my browser. There must be something I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help me see it.

thanks

Comment: do you own the server ?

Comment: It's within my company but we are not the owners

Comment: Maybe you need to use a proxy to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe they check the user agent, try to forge it :

`setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36");`

But it's definitely server side, you should ask your team, maybe some parameters are missing.

Comment: thanks. I did find out the problem was to do with communication between the two servers.